Origins of the Elephant trap name
Is it true that the Elephant trap is named after the original diagonal moving piece from Chaturanga? I know that in Russian the bishop is still referred to as the elephant, but does anyone know the historical origin of the name. "Elephant Trap"; I've read somewhere that it came from the Russian word for bishop.
https://pinsandgambits.com/queensGambitDeclined.html#elephantTrap

The original piece was indeed called an elephant, which is the source of Russian "slon" ("elephant") for the modern Bishop, as well as the Spanish "alfil" (from Arabic al-fil, "the elephant") and related words in other languages.  But it was a much weaker piece -- e.g. the medieval alfil/elephant is a (2,2)-leaper -- and the opening trap wouldn't work if the modern Bishops were replaced by the old elephant.

That I understand, what I'm asking is why is the trap called the elephant trap? what is the significance of the name? I've found a number of sources, but cannot verify which one is true.
